# Retrieving multidimensional cookie values with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, cookies

I am storing a cookie with:

```
context.Response.Cookies["visitorData"]["lastDateVisited"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
context.Response.Cookies[_visitorData].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
```

I can get the same cookie in C# using this script:

```
cookyval = context.Request.Cookies["visitorData"]["lastDateVisited"];
```

How can I retrive the cookie value using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help [JavaScript and Cookies](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/)

Answer (score 0):

Multivalued / multidimensional cookies are handled differently by different implementations, but the concept is essentially the same.

They use a delimiter character within the value part of the cookie to separate out the name value pairs.

Google uses the pipe character (`|`) as a delimiter and .NET uses the ampersand (`&`) as a delimiter.

If you set the cookie as you have in the code above the result would be the following;

```
//.NET
context.Response.Cookies["visitorData"]["lastDateVisited"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
context.Response.Cookies["visitorData"]["example2"] = "sillyString";
context.Response.Cookies[_visitorData].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);

// JavaScript Console
console.log(document.cookie)
visitorData=lastDateVisited=14/05/2012 16:09:09&example2=sillyString; other cookies here
```

You can now find `visitorData=` in `document.cookie` and `substr()` until the following `;`.
Then `split()` that into name-value pairs.